# Solve the differential equation using substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the integral curve of the differential equation $$x(1-x\ln y)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$ which passes through $(1,1/e)$.

It looks like some king of substitution. I did try some exponential substitution but they were useless. Some hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What about $y=e^u,dy=e^udu$? This results in $x(1-xu)\frac{du}{dx}=-1$, which is not obviously separable, but simpler.

Comment: @Kajelad yeah, that is what I tried. It does simplify, but it still gives problems.

Comment: @User1upon0 after that substitution, you can separate variables and it solves easily after that.

Comment: @D.Dmitriy could you please post a solution?

Comment: @User1upon0 sorry, I've made a mistake. it's a little bit more involved than that.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a change of variables $$ t=\ln{y}$$ $$z=\frac{1}{x}$$ Then the equation becomes $$\frac{dz}{dt}=z-t$$ This is a linear equation, you will be able to solve it by finding the formula online.